# Subversion resolving conflicts manually not telling me the username of conflicting change

Tags: svn

```
<<<<<<< .mine
echo 'yo you're tidy';
=======
echo 'spfkopsdkfo;
>>>>>>> .r11
```

Ben committed  the other change. Is it possible for it to automatically insert the username so that I knew it was ben that made revision 11?

I'm aware I could explore the repository to find out it was ben that made the last commit. I'm also aware there is a commit hook script that can send emails when commit is made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you look at `svn blame` ? That doesn't attribute the diff to who changed this, but on the hand it gives you last author and revision for every line of the file(s) you point it at.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible for it to automatically insert the username so that I knew it was ben that made revision 11?

Short answer: No.

Somewhat longer answer: Theoretically, a diff tool could do this for you, but in practice I haven't seen one.

Answer (score 0):

if the conflict is only over one line, then it would be possible (but it's not implemented in svn).
But imagine a conflict that covers multiple lines: There could be multiple authors for those multiple lines - which one should be shown? All of them?